# Объясните для чего в классе объявляется переменная этого же класса?

Tags: java

Объясните для чего в классе объявляется переменная этого же класса?

```
public class Person {

    static Person personInner;

    String name, age;

    private Person(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Person getInstance(String name, String age){
        if (personInner == null){
            personInner = new Person(name, age);
        }
        return personInner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: она используется в ситуации, когда Персон болен раздвоением личности

Comment: ссорян за тупой вопрос.

Comment: Из того кода, что Вы привели, невозможно определить, зачем нужен этот член класса. Сейчас подойдут телепаты и выскажут свое мнение.

Comment: @Igor а для Персон с множественным расщеплением сознания нужно возвращать список (или массив) xD

Comment: @AlexChermenin Да, архитектор плохо изучил бизнес-сторону задачи.

Comment: этот person уже рекурсивный, значит можно вернуть бесконечным списком. А то, что возраст указывается строкой, позволяет сохранять совсем странных персон. Отсюда вывод - это последствия того, что хаскелист решил писать на java.

Comment: очень остроумно парни))

Comment: Поправьте если не правильно сформулировал:
Если переменная класса объявлена в классе, то такой класс соответствует паттерну одиночка. При этом переменная статична, и создать более одного экземпляра класса невозможно.

Comment: Нет, неправильно. Для синглтона в коде должно присутствовать слово `static` (хотя бы в комментариях :)).

Comment: public static class Person ?

Comment: Ух, как сильно изменился вопрос! Буквально на 15 минут отошел. Теперь это модель общества, состоящего из одного человека.

Answer (score 4):

Хороший вопрос, логика данного кода

1. Если getInstance вызывался в первый раз, объект Person создается с нужным именем и возрастом,
2. При вызовах getInstance во второй и следующий раз, возвращается объект Person созданный в первый раз, а имя и возраст игнорируются.

Это классический паттерн Сингелтон (или одиночка). Правда в данном случае это выглядит как ошибка. Так как это плохой дизайн, когда имя и возраст у getInstance просто игнорируются, получается пользователь API запрашивает определенный данные, а ему возвращается что-то не связанное с тем именем и возрастом, который он запросил. Получается что мы всегда работает с одним человеком, созданным первым. Можно было бы это понять если в getInstance менялись имя и возраст - это было бы переиспользование  ненужного объекта (хотя такое тоже редко).

**P.S.** Так же странным решением выглядят не приватные внутренние поля, я бы сделал

```
private static Person personInner;
private String name;
private String age;
```

Ну или если ожидается что у класса будет созданы потомки, которые будут работать с этими полями, то использовал бы protected, видимость уровня класса кажется явно лишней.

А откуда код взят? Вы уверены, что он действительно делает то что и задумалось?